# Where can I find RHOAR maven artifacts for WildFly Swarm and Vert.x?

Tags: redhat-rhoar

I currently use WildFly Swarm and Vert.x maven artifacts from the Maven Central repository. However, I do not see the same artifacts in the Red Hat Maven Repository  Can someone point me to where the maven artifacts are?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking at the GA repository. While the product is in beta, please refer to the early access repository. When the product reaches general availability [GA], the artifacts will be moved to the GA repository